# Assigning value of a class instance variable starting with __ outside the class.

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

I am quite new to python and was just trying to understand how object oriented programming works in it. I have read that using a double _(underscore) in front of a variable signifies that its value cannot be changed outside of the class. To test it I tried running the following snippet.

```
class a:
    def set_value(self,x):
        self.__x = x
    def get_value(self):
        return self.__x

a_obj = a()
a_obj.set_value(10)
a_obj.__x = 1
print a_obj.__x
print a_obj.get_value()
```

The output of this comes up to be

```
1
10
```

I don't understand this behavior. When I check the id of both the variables, it comes to be different. I know that there is a concept of name mangling but I don't fully understand if what I am doing is indeed that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Python

When you assigned to __x outside of the class you didn't change the existing class variable but instead created a new one. The existing one was mangled to _a__x while you created a new one which really was __x

Try adding this to the end of your code:

```
print a_obj._a__x
```